# Adding multiple SSRS reports into one report is very slow

Tags: ssrs-2012, subreports

I inherited a report from a developer where he combined 5 reports into one SSRS report.  It looks like he just copied and pasted each tablix from the original reports one below the other.  This was done so that when the user exports to Excel they can have each report on a separate tab.  I've never done a multiple SSRS report like this before so I'm just now analyzing how this whole thing works.  A major problem I'm finding is that it runs extremely slow, about 10 minutes, seemingly because it has to run all 5 queries.  Each stored procedure is listed separately as a data set.  Does anyone know a better way to create multiple SSRS reports onto one page, or at least how to make this thing faster?

Answer (score 1):

The first step to improving performance for an SSRS report is to determine what the bottleneck is.  Run a query against the view named  ExecutionLog4 in the ReportServer database.  For each recent execution of a report, the view will give you a record that includes 3 critical fields: TimeDataRetrieval, TimeProcessing, and TimeRendering.

TimeDataRetrieval indicates how long (in milliseconds) it takes for all of the queries to run and return your datasets.  If this number is high, then you will need to tune your queries or eliminate some of them to improve performance.  You can run a profiler trace to identify which of the procedures is running slowly.

Keep in mind also that subreports fire their dataset queries each time they are rendered in the report.  So even a minor performance hiccup in a subreports dataset gets magnified by the number of executions.

TimeProcessing indicates how much time the report server spends manipulating the retrieved data.  If this number is high, you may want to consider performing aggregate calculations that are being run many times within a report to run on the SQL side.

TimeRendering indicates how long the server takes to actually render the report.  If this number is high, consider avoiding or simplifying expressions used on visual properties that repeat over and over again.  This scenario is less common than the other two, in my experience.

Furthermore, here are some tips I've picked up that help to avoid performance issues:

-Avoid using row visibility expressions if you expect a large number of rows to be returned.
-Hiding an object does not prevent dataset execution.  If your datasets have similar structure, consider combining them and using object filters to limit what is displayed in different sections.  Or use an IF statement in your stored procedure if you only intend to display one of several choices depending on data or parameters.
-Try to limit the number of column groupings in a large tablix.  For each grouping in a tablix, you multiply the number of rows of data that may be returned to pivot into those groupings.

More info on SSRS performance can be found at 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522806(v=sql.105).aspx
This was written for 2008R2, but seems mostly applicable to 2012 as well.

Give all that a shot, then post back here with a more specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: Unfortunately I have limited permissions at work and I won't be able to run anything against ExecutionLog4.  My first step is to rewrite each of these queries and see if that will help.

Comment: That's a shame.  I always shake my head when organizations task someone with improving something and deprive them of the appropriate tools to do so...